# Generic inheritance and Delegates

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, dictionary

Straight to the point. Lets say I have a simple inheritance model

```
class Base {}
class Inh : Base {}
```

and I want to do something like this (note - this code does not compile):

```
class Test
{
    private Dictionary<Type, Action<Base>> dict;

    public Test()
    {
         dict = new Dictionary<Type, Action<Base>>();
    }

    public void Test(Inh inh)
    {
    }

    public void Add<T>(Action<T> callback) 
        where T : BasePackage
    {
        dict.Add(typeof(T), callback);
    }
}
```

The main idea is to use the dictionary as a function caller. For example if I added the `Test` func as a callback, I could later do something like this:

```
dict[typeof(Inh)](new Inh());
```

Unfortunately I cannot find the soulution myself so I am asking for help. If anyone has any suggestions it would be appreciated.

Comment: I have a feeling you may be approaching this from the wrong direction.

Comment: Why mix inheritance + function table?

Comment: What is the actual goal here?  How do you plan to use this?

Comment: `dict.Add(callback.GetType(), callback);` doesn't work?

Comment: is `public void Test.Test(Inh inh)` a method or a mistyped constructor?

Comment: yea 'public void Test(Inh inh)' is a method - its my mistake

Comment: I feel what you are trying to achieve can be done through virtual methods.  I see Type.Action(new Inh()) why not just normal method? on the Type?

Comment: @MBen, you might use a pattern somewhat like this if you wanted to dynamically associate a behavior with a class type without modifying the original type.  This could be used as a slightly awkward Strategy pattern, with different options for the type of strategy you associated with a given type.

Comment: @DanBryant by dynamic you mean runtime? otherwise I would go for extension methods, much cleaner.

Comment: @MBen, At runtime, yes and with the possibility to have different behaviors 'loaded' depending on user feedback, for example.  There are cleaner ways to accomplish this, but that's the general idea behind this kind of dynamic dispatch.

Comment: What's the relationship between Base and BasePackage, if any?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this to coerce the type.  Note that this can fail at runtime (due to an invalid cast) if you ever look up and call the delegate for the wrong type.  That possible failure case is why this does not meet the criteria for automatic contravariance in delegate usage.

```
public void Add<T>(Action<T> callback) 
        where T : Base
    {
        dict.Add(typeof(T), Base b => callback((T)b));
    }
```